# Algorithmic efficiency

Tags: performance, sorting

I'm trying to write a code with O(n+k) efficiency. The function input is a list and I have to sort it.

It's known that:

- every `x` in list is either an integer or `x=y+0.5`
- `k` is `(-k)<=x<=(k)` for every `x` in the list
- `n` is the number of items in the list

*the original list has to stay the same

Here is my code with efficiency problems in the for loop.
Any suggestions?

```
def sort_num_list(lst):
    lst2=[n*2 for n in lst] ##O(N)
    k=max(abs(i) for i in lst2)##O(N)
    lst1=[]
    for i in range(-k,k+1):
        if i in lst2:
            lst2.remove(i)
            lst1.append(i)
            if i in lst2:
                lst1.append(i)
    lst1=[n/2 for n in lst1] ##O(N)
    return lst1
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort with a couple extra bits (one of which is multiply by two to make everything integer that you're already doing, the other is to make everything a valid array index by adding `2k`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't do python, but here's what a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) applied to your problem would look like in C++:

```
// find the maximum absolute value
int k = .1 + std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), 0.0,
                              [](double m, double e){return std::max(m, std::abs(e));}
                            );

// size the count array
std::vector<int> counts(4*k+1);

// count them all
for( auto e : input ) ++counts[2*k + int(2*e + .1)];

// growable array
std::vector<double> result;

// but we already know what size it will be (optional step)
result.reserve(std::distance(input.begin(), input.end()));

// turn counts into that many elements, in iteration order (thus sorted)
for( int i = 0; i < counts.size(); ++i )
    result.resize(result.size() + counts[i], i/2.0 - k);
```

Actually in real code I probably would not use `std::accumulate` to find the max absolute value.  `std::max_element` won't work because we need absolute values.  A ranged-for loop would solve the problem trivially and be much easier to verify correctness.

```
int k = 0;
for( auto e : input ) k = std::max(k, int(2*e + .1));
```

The `+.1` terms are there because I don't trust that there is no rounding error in the input array.